# DualBoot, Win10 Won't Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

(Just learning Ubuntu and Linux, so easy on the acros and Linux-speak please!)
Installed Ubuntu 16.04 from DVD selecting dual install alongside Windows 10 on my old Acer Aspire 5542. Followed the install guide and Ubuntu installed very nicely. Problem is that I don't know how to boot back into Win10. When I start my laptop, it boots directly to Ubuntu with no other option. 
Any suggestions on how to access Win10? (Frankly, I'd rather just erase Win10, but I would want to first make certain that Ubuntu gets all the disk space it needs with nothing going to waste.)

Comment: Open a Terminal and run `sudo update-grub`. Let it finish and reboot. You should now see a Grub menu with Ubuntu and Windows. Update your question with the results by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Make sure Windows 10's fast start up is off or else os-prober which is run with the update of grub may not see it https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running. If you do not have if off and system is BIOS, you have to use your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to fix/boot into Windows.

Comment: Yes, that's true and the system is from circa 2009 so probably BIOS, the OP apparently chose the option if "install alongside" without making room first so the installer shrunk the the semi-hibernated Windows partitions... Everything that shouldn't have been done was done anyway, So, yes, time to boot Windows media to fix it. Then fix Grub, again.